# Unexpected dtype of (originally) timestamp after aggregating 2-level grupby object with min()

Tags: python, group-by, pandas, timestamp

This might be related to this resolved question/bug:

[Unexpected results of min() and max() methods of Pandas series made of Timestamp objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12974404/unexpected-results-of-min-and-max-methods-of-pandas-series-made-of-timestamp/)

This time, the problem is with aggregating with min() and max() methods on Timestamp/datetime column within *multilevel* groupby object. The resulting column seems to be integer not expected Timestamp/datetime.

```
In [3]: pd.__version__
Out[3]: '0.13.0'

In [4]: np.__version__
Out[4]: '1.8.0'

In [5]: rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=10, freq='4h')
In [6]: lvl1 = ['A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B']
In [7]: lvl2 = ['foo','foo','bar','bar','bar','foo','foo','foo','bar','bar']
In [8]: df = pd.DataFrame({'TS': rng, 'V' : np.random.randn(len(rng)), 'L1' : lvl1, 'L2' : lvl2})

In [9]: df
Out[9]:
  L1   L2                  TS         V
0  A  foo 2000-01-01 00:00:00  1.084908
1  A  foo 2000-01-01 04:00:00  1.650871
2  A  bar 2000-01-01 08:00:00  1.884018
3  A  bar 2000-01-01 12:00:00 -1.196144
4  A  bar 2000-01-01 16:00:00 -1.249594
5  B  foo 2000-01-01 20:00:00 -1.426138
6  B  foo 2000-01-02 00:00:00  0.413785
7  B  foo 2000-01-02 04:00:00  0.507160
8  B  bar 2000-01-02 08:00:00  1.369455
9  B  bar 2000-01-02 12:00:00  2.229319
```

Using min() on one-level groupby seems to work as expected, timestamps are Timestamps.

```
In [10]: df.groupby(['L1']).min()
Out[10]:
     L2                  TS         V
L1
A   bar 2000-01-01 00:00:00 -0.995938
B   bar 2000-01-01 20:00:00 -1.582318
```

This is the troubling part; after aggregating 2-level grouby object with min(), the TS column is in int64's.

```
In [11]: df.groupby(['L1', 'L2']).min()
Out[11]:
                        TS         V
L1 L2
A  bar  946713600000000000 -0.607672
   foo  946684800000000000 -0.995938
B  bar  946800000000000000 -0.019575
   foo  946756800000000000 -1.582318

In [12]: df.groupby(['L1', 'L2']).min().dtypes
Out[12]:
TS      int64
V     float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: The problem seems to have been fix as of pandas 0.13.1.

Comment: Oh, I guess this issue
https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5869
thank you @unutbu