# Unexpected parsing of Timestamps reading pandas dataframe from .csv file

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I have a pandas dataframe read from a csv file which includes a column of dates

```
In[1]: df = pd.read_csv(fileStats, index_col=0, parse_dates= ['start_date'])

In[2]: df.head()
Out[3]:
                 start_date  
    customer_ID                                                               
    10006414       2012-10-02 08:30:00   
    10006486       2013-12-02 09:00:00   
    10006492       2013-12-02 09:00:00   
    10006572       2012-03-31 08:30:00   
    10006630       2012-01-06 10:30:00
```

I want to find the earliest date:

```
In[4]: df['start_date'].min()
Out[5]:
Timestamp('2011-01-12 08:00:00')
```

which looks fine *except* that when I open the .csv file in excel, and order the rows by `start_date`, the earliest date is `2011-10-06 13:00:00`. The same problem happens with `.max()`  This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12974404/unexpected-results-of-min-and-max-methods-of-pandas-series-made-of-timestamp) refers to a similar problem, but related to np.datetime64 which I am not using here. Is there an issue with `.max()` and `.min()` or is it to do with parsing the dates in `.read_csv` ?

EDIT:
Further investigation on suggestions from @DYZ shows that the Timestamps have been read or parsed incorrectly.  `6/10/2011 13:00` in the .csv file has become `2014-03-03 10:00:00` in the dataframe. How to correct this?

Comment: Start by checking the earliest date is _in_ `df`.

Comment: `In[6]: earliest = df['start_date'].min()`
`In[7]: earliest in df`
`Out[8]: 
False`

Comment: `earliest in df` does not check if a row is in a dataframe. Check `earliest in df['start_date'].values`.

Comment: `earliest in df['start_date'].values` returns `False`

Comment: So, looks like that line was not read, or was not read correctly, or was not parsed correctly. I would check id the number of rows in `df` and in the CSV file is the same.

Comment: Good suggestion. Yes they have the same number of rows. Looking at the specific `customer_ID` shows that the timestamp been read or parsed incorrectly. `6/10/2011 13:00` has become `2014-03-03 10:00:00`

Comment: My guess is that it actually reads `6/10/2011 13:00` as `2011-06-10 13:00:00` and `01/12/2011 08:00:00` as `2011-01-12 08:00:00`. Try adding `dayfirst=True` as an argument to `pd.read_csv`.